# Comparison of various home-automation systems?

Tags: home-automation

Could anyone provide a comparison (or just link) of home-automation systems (such as FS 20, HomeEasy, RSL, ...)? (Wikipedia contains just a [short list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_automation#Comparison_of_popular_protocols) and I am unable to find something something neutral and more comprehensive.)

Comment: @Tester101 How can I improve the question?

Comment: There are websites which specialize in HA systems; I'd suggest you do a bit of websearching and check them out. Brand recommendations are almost always considered offtopic here; if you have specific how-to questions about the installation and use of these systems those would be a better fit.

Comment: I have found several sites regarding HA systems, but no comprehensive NPOV comparison of them.

Comment: @TN: maintaining that comprehensive NPOV comparison table on a global scale on even a weekly basis would be too much to expect from a site like this.

Comment: From what I've seen, most of them work about equivalently and the question is really one of preferred technology, whether the functions you want are available in that family, whether the family is available from multiple vendors (which can be helpful both in price and in reassuring you that they'll continue to be available/supported in the future), and price (which as always is continuously variable). If you rephrase this as _technology_ tradeoffs, there may be some things we can say which will be useful for more than a month or two.