# List of home automation systems?

Tags: home-automation

As @keshlam explained me in
[Comparison of various home-automation systems?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/55364/comparison-of-various-home-automation-systems#comment76990_55364), it is not possible to get up-to-date [NPOV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Neutral_point_of_view) comparison of various home automation systems.

What about a list of home-automation systems/protocols (maybe with basic parameters, such as wired/wireless, etc.)?

Comment: It seems to me that this list will change over time, and would be difficult; if not impossible, to maintain in this format.

Comment: @Tester101 This question is not seeking product or service recommendations. Just to create a list of them.

Comment: This question has the same problem, in that the products will change over time. Which means the answer must also change. This is not a good fit to the format of the site.

Comment: Which StackExchange site should I use? ("Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve." - I am new to home automation and I'd like to choose a suitable home automation system.)

Answer (score 3):

The following protocols are [listed in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_automation#Comparison_of_popular_protocols):

- C-Bus: [@wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-Bus_%28protocol%29)
- EnOcean: [@wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EnOcean)
- Insteon: [@wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insteon)
- KNX: [@wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KNX_%28standard%29)
- UPB: [@wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_powerline_bus)
- X10: [@wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X10_%28industry_standard%29)
- Zigbee: [@wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZigBee)
- Z-Wave: [@wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-Wave)

In addition to these, I know there are the following systems:

- FS20
- HomeEasy
- HomeMatic
- iComfort
- Kopp FreeControl
- Belkin WEMO: [@wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belkin_WEMO)
- Intertechno
- ELRO

Actually, I do not know whether some of these systems do not use some protocols above.

There are already some question concerning this topic:

- [Which communication bus systems for home automation?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/333/which-communication-bus-systems-for-home-automation)
- [What are some scalable, affordable home automation options?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/2984/what-are-some-scalable-affordable-home-automation-options)
- [What are the pros and cons of different types of smart switches (that are on the US market) ?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/384/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-different-types-of-smart-switches-that-are-on-the)

Comment: See also the questions in the "Related" column on the right side of this page.